# Не получается установить MySQL на Termux

Tags: android, mysql, linux, эмулятор

Приветствую.

Я пытаюсь установить MySQL на эмулятор терминала [Termux](https://termux.com/) на Android, но получаю ошибку:

```
Unable to locate package mysql-server
```

Делал `apt-get update`, не помогло:

[image: screen]

P.S. PHP7, vim, cowsay, elinks установились и работают прекрасно, поэтому есть основания принять этот эмулятор за обычный терминал Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL не добавлен в список пакетов Termux, который можно посмотреть на [GitHub](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages). Судя по открытому [тикету](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/216), MySQL пока перемещён в список предложений.